# Is an airline required to compensate a damaged suitcase with money or can they give me a suitcase voucher?

Tags: european-union, air-travel

An airline damaged my suitcase and gave me a suitcase voucher that I can redeem on their website. However I would like to get money instead. I know they have to reimburse me according to Montreal Convention, but are they allowed to do it with a voucher or can I insist on a bank transfer?

According to https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261&from=EN

> The compensation referred to in paragraph 1 shall be paid in cash, by electronic bank transfer, bank orders or bank cheques or, with the signed agreement of the passenger, in travel vouchers and/or other services.

But this only refers to flight delays/cancellations and I'm not sure if it's also relevant for baggage claims.

Comment: That regulation is not relevant to lost baggage claims. It only applies to cases where you've been denied boarding or your flight has been cancelled or delayed.

Comment: @JBentley thanks, that's what I thought as well. Does a similar regulation regarding baggage claims exist?

Comment: @JBentley did you see the last sentence of the question?

Comment: @phoog Yes, that's what my comment is in reply to. The OP stated they weren't sure if it applied to baggage; I was clarifying. It didn't seem worth an answer by itself.

Comment: @JBentley I see!   I read "I'm not sure if it's also relevant" as more of an implicit "I understand that it isn't relevant," but on reflection that interpretation makes little sense in light of YuseqYaseq's having included it in the question.